# Check when the video reached the end of it

Tags: javascript, html

I want to check when the movie has reached to the very end of it. As we know when the video is finished it pauses. I want to check right this moment:

So I tried to get the total duration of the video and check if the video current time is more than that point:

```js
var vid = document.getElementById("myVideo");

checkTime();


async function checkTime() {

  const durationOfMovie = await getDuration(); 
  console.log("durationOfMovie", durationOfMovie);
  
  const doSomethingWithTheFrame = (now, metadata) => {
    console.log("metadata.mediaTime", metadata.mediaTime);
    // We want to check this to detect the movie reached the End
    if(metadata.mediaTime >= durationOfMovie) {
        console.log("Movie Reached The End");
        return;
    }
    vid.requestVideoFrameCallback(doSomethingWithTheFrame);
    };
  // Initially register the callback to be notified about the first frame.
  vid.requestVideoFrameCallback(doSomethingWithTheFrame);
}

function getDuration() {
  return new Promise((resolve) => {        
    vid.addEventListener("durationchange", checkDuration);
    function checkDuration() {
      if(this.duration !== Infinity) {
        vid.removeEventListener("durationchange", checkDuration);
        const duration = this.duration;
        return resolve(duration);
      }
    }
    vid.load();
    vid.currentTime = 3000; // fake time
  });
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html> 
<html> 
<body> 
  <video id="myVideo" width="320" height="176" controls>
    <source src="https://www.w3schools.com/tags/mov_bbb.mp4" type="video/mp4">
  </video>
</body> 
</html>
```

But As you see the `durationOfMovie` is always more than what `metadata.mediaTime` could show so we could never check the end of the video!!!

Why this is not working?

For different videos the difference between `durationOfMovie` and `metadata.mediaTime` is different and that makes more confusion...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's an `ended` event: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLMediaElement/ended_event

```
vid.addEventListener('ended', () => console.log("it's over"));
```